# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm doing a simple program for converting temperatures with Kelvin, Celsius and Fahrenheit, but I'm getting this error when doing anything with kelvin:

```
Cannon implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'
```

The line the error occurs:

```
public static float FahrenheitToKelvin(float fahrenheit)
{
    return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9 + 273.15;
}
```

The button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var input = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    float FahrenResult = FahrenheitToCelsius(input);
    textBox2.Text = FahrenResult.ToString();
    float KelvinResult = FahrenheitToKelvin(input);
    textBox3.Text = KelvinResult.ToString();
}
```

And the test method I'm trying to make:

```
[TestMethod]
public void fahrenheitToKelvinBoiling()
{
    float fahrenheit = 212F;
    float expected = 373.15F; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    float actual;
    actual = Form1.FahrenheitToKelvin(fahrenheit);
    Assert.AreEqual(Math.Round(expected, 2), Math.Round(actual, 2));
    // Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this.

```
    public static float FahrenheitToKelvin(float fahrenheit)
    {
        return ((fahrenheit - 32f) * 5f) / 9f + 273.15f;
    }
```

This works because it changes the compiler from recognizing the 32 5 and so on as doubles. The f after the number tells the compiler it is a float.

Comment: If this solved it please mark question as solved and click the checkmark to make this the answer to the question.

Comment: Ya i normally do. But yes i shouldv'e explained. I will put in an explanation.

Comment: Cool, though the most salient point is that the OP was using floats consistently (or so he thought) but all decimal-like literals are by default `double` unless they have a qualifier such as `F` or `M`.  And once you start operating against a `double` all the other operands get implicitly converted into doubles, and thus the result could not be implicitly contained inside a `float` return type.

Comment: OO thanks for that info. I am still very new to programming. I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is promoting the resulting expression to a double. I think it assumes that those numbers which includes a decimal part are double.

Nevertheless you can explicitly convert the resulting value to a float;

or you can try to explicitly convert all your constants that have a decimal separator to a float.

**EDIT**

As a side note, are you perfectly comfortable with using a floats (or doubles) instead of decimals? I don't see your code, eventually **when displaying data to the user interface** by invoking the **ToString**() method, rounding the value to a certain number of precision digits (although your unit test does it).

**You might get some "lost" precision digits at the end of you float** and they'll get displayed to the UI by using ToString().

I'd strongly suggest either:

1. Use round to a certain decimal precision
2. Change the floats to decimals